# Codeigniter shopping cart not working after adding expire headers via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cart, expires-header

I am developing a shopping cart website with codeigniter. when I add expire headers cart functionality not working properly. give below is my .htaccess code

```
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.samajamonline\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/samajamonline\.com\/" [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Only after refreshing items are showing on my shopping cart and also destroy cart function is also not working

Comment: everything workes fine when i removed header expire section

Comment: So most likely some internal resource / endpoint that wasn’t supposed to get cached, is getting cached now. I’d start by removing the `ExpiresDefault`, and see if that changes things.